# Magnetism: EMF induced by a conducting balloon filling with water

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

### Info:

As stated in the title, I'm wondering how to find the EMF induced by a conducting balloon. This balloon is under a waterfall, and it expands and contracts as water is filled in it, with a flow rate F (in $\frac{m^3}{s}$). The balloon is also in a uniform magnetic field B. We can assume the balloon to be spherical in shape.

### Question:

At a certain time, the balloon has a volume $V_0$. What will the EMF induced by the balloon be at that time around its horizontal equator?

### Thoughts:

What came to my mind is to use Faraday's law: $emf = -\frac{d\phi_m}{dt}$. The trouble I faced when doing this was that I got stuck trying to figure out what the Flux is. Using Ampere's Law, I set $\oint\vec{B} \cdot \vec{dl} = \mu_0 * I$, but I realise I'm not given a current; only a field. Not only that, but the radius of the balloon would change as it expands and contracts, so the radius would not be constant either. So my question becomes how would I apply Ampere's Law to work around this? Also, since the EMF induced would depend on the flow rate, how would I take that into account when calculating the flux?

Any help given would be much appreciated!